# How do i put a condition on one of the columns in sqlite in android?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a column named `expense` and I want the user to input expense and for a month that expense to get added in the `expense` column of the database and then whenever I output the user expense it displays the whole sum of expenses that user has entered on button click. please help me with the code I'm a noob.

Answer (score 0):

```
public int getTotalExpense()
{
    int rv = 0;
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cur = db.rawQuery("SELECT SUM(expense) FROM myTable", null);
    if(cur.moveToFirst())
    {
        rv = cur.getInt(0);
    }
    cur.close();
    return rv;
}
```

create a seperate method and use above query to achieve what you want.